# Separate variable to $1 $2 $3

Tags: linux, bash

```
sqlite3 pcheck.db "SELECT * FROM printers"
```

gives me:

```
 1|10.0.0.x|HP4250INK|public|hp LaserJet 4250|"CNHXXXXXX"|14457|"Sleep Mode"
```

i want to put the data separated by | into variables $1 to $8

so that is can output it like

```
echo "$1 $3 $5"
echo "$2 $4 $6"
```

./test.sh

```
1 HP4250INK hp Laserjet 4250
10.0.0.x public "CNHXXXXXX"
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can just use bash without external tools

```
output=$(sqlite3 pcheck.db "SELECT * FROM printers")
IFS="|"
set -- $output
echo $1
echo $2 #and so on
```

or use arrays

```
IFS="|"
output=($(sqlite3 pcheck.db "SELECT * FROM printers"))
echo ${output[0]}
echo ${output[1]} #and so on
```

Comment: Nice, what does `set -- $output` do?

Comment: if you look at the man page for `bash` under `set`, ` Any
              arguments remaining after option processing are treated as values for the positional parameters and are assigned, in order,  to
              $1, $2, ...  $n.`

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
echo $YOUR_STRING | cut -d'|' -f1,3,5
```

for the first three, and

```
echo $YOUR_STRING | cut -d'|' -f2,4,6
```

for the other three.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `awk` for this :)

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" } ; { print $1 " " $3 " " $5 }'
```

Or:

```
awk 'BEGIN { FS = "|" } ; { printf "%s\t%st\%s\n%s\t%s\t%s", $1, $3, $5, $2, $4, $6 }'
```